# Gulp - Sourcemapping less while combining media queries

Tags: gulp, less, media-queries

In this project I am leveraging "Gulp" for some tasks, but recently got a request to add sourcemapping..

I have the sourcemap working, but it seems to have a conflict with other plugins like `'gulp-combine-mq'` and `"gulp-combine-media-queries"`  ***aka "cmq"***

When running my styles task with "cmq" commented out, i get my sourcemap exactly how i expect it

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  gulp.src('./assets/src/less/main.less')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(less().on('error', gutil.log))
    //.pipe(cmqs().on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css'));
});
```

[image]

When I try to use "cmq", it messes up the mapping

[image]

Has anyone else had this issue using gulp, less, combine-media-queries or combine-mq?

Does anyone have suggestions on how to address this issue?

- thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/konitter/gulp-combine-media-queries/issues/5

Comment: thanks for that @SLaks - just submitted an issue on combine-mq github as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to use [gulp-minify-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) for your minify task (if you not already do) because of gulp-minify-css passes its options are directly passed to [clean-css](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/).

clean-css does support media query merging now, see: https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/commit/6ed784a4aae91e5d7f48cf189c24095dfb8062cd

Comment: thanks @Bass - i do use gulp-minify-css but will try the clean. I ended up rearranging the less myself in order to get sourcemaps